# gtx1050 and gtx1060 in one PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Excuse my English, I will try to explain this problem.

I have one GeForce GTX1050 2GB for one monitor and A GeForce GTX1060 3GB for another monitor. Don't ask why, I have my reasons.

Before adding the GTX1060, I had a GT610 card in that slot.  When I move Google Chrome (for example) from the monitor attached to the GT 610 to the monitor attached to the GTX 1050, the GTX 1050 parameters (GPU Load, etc) increased and GT 610 load decreased, which seemed appropriate.

Now, with the GTX 1060 and  GTX 1050, when I do the same thing, the 1050 always keeps working like the window is on the monitor connected to the GTX 1050. Work load on the GTX 1060 increases, but the GTX 1050 still got pretty much of it.

The NVIDIA control panel "GPU activity icon" shows me everything is running on the GTX 1050, but I am doing everything on the monitor with GTX 1060. On the monitor with GTX 1050 I only have Outlook open and no other app.

Can someone explain to me why is that happening?

Comment: Windows can use one GPU with video ports on another GPU. Maybe your GPU load is not high and Windows wants to keep one GPU in the lowest power state like 10W. You may try to disable 1050, then re enable it.BTW you don't need two GPU at all you can disable one.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx provides some possibly useful facts to think about.

The 1050 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq15o.jpg and 1060 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek6du.jpg cards use the same driver, version 442.92.

The 610 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFR5q.jpg uses a significantly different driver, version 391.35.

If you don't need to process data with a different driver, then it stands to reason the load parameters will change, but if the same driver will be doing the processing for both cards, then a different driver does not need to be loaded.